# SQL Server performance issue: Why simple SQL statements and a UD scalar-valued function appear to be expensive

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-performance

We've been experiencing some severe performance issues on our SQL 2008 r2 DB.  When we run the Activity Monitor in SQL Server Management Studio, and a SP that returns who/what is active, it shows the following three transactions as being very expensive:

**Query 1:**

```
SET @DateMonth = '0' + @DateMonth
```

**Query 2:**

```
SET @DateMonth = CAST(datepart(mm, @TheDate) AS VARCHAR(2))
```

**Function:**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DateToNGDate] (@TheDate datetime)
RETURNS VARCHAR(10)
AS
BEGIN
            DECLARE @DateYear VARCHAR(4)
            DECLARE @DateMonth VARCHAR(2)
            DECLARE @DateDay VARCHAR(2)

            SET @DateYear = CAST(datepart(yyyy, @TheDate) AS VARCHAR(4))

            SET @DateMonth = CAST(datepart(mm, @TheDate) AS VARCHAR(2))
            IF (LEN (@DateMonth) = 1) SET @DateMonth = '0' + @DateMonth

            SET @DateDay = CAST(datepart(dd, @TheDate) AS VARCHAR(2))
            IF (LEN (@DateDay) = 1) SET @DateDay = '0' + @DateDay

            RETURN @DateYear+@DateMonth+@DateDay
END
```

That last one comes back like that, but i'm pretty sure it isn't creating the function (it already exists), rather it is just running it.  It is also the one that comes up the most as appearing to be a performance killer (it's used throughout our code).

I'm sure these aren't what is actually causing the problem, but why would they appear as they are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scalar-valued functions are a known performance issue in SQL Server. One option is to define your function like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DateToNGDateX] (@TheDate datetime)
RETURNS table as return 
(
    select
        cast(
              CAST(datepart(yyyy, @TheDate) AS VARCHAR(4)) -- DateYear 
            + right('0' + CAST(datepart(mm, @TheDate) AS VARCHAR(2)),2) -- DateMonth 
            + right('0' + CAST(datepart(dd, @TheDate) AS VARCHAR(2)),2) -- DateDay 
        as varchar(30)) as Value
)
```

and reference it like this:

```
select Value from [dbo].[DateToNGDateX] ('20140110');
```

However, for the specific functionality you desire, test this as well:

```
select convert(char(8), cast('20140110' as date), 112);
```

which will return a *date* formatted as *yyyymmdd*.

Comment: How is this all the sudden a big issue for us?  This was never a problem for years (6+), but out of no where it's killing us.  Also, this isn't a function we wrote inhouse, we support an EHR product called NextGen, and this was a stock function of theirs.

Comment: @jreed121: I cannot explain why EHR would have unsupervised junior programmers on staff who wouldn't know of this issue; you have to take that up with them. As for why it is suddenly an issue, I suggest posting a Query Plan. Regardless, the correct way to attain this functionality is to use one of the two methods I describe above, and test to see which one works best in your environment.

Answer (score 1):

Scalar UDFs are very slow if your select statement is returning a lot of rows, because they are going to be executed once for every row that is returned. Maybe you can rewrite as an inline function as per this link [inline UDFs](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alexander_kuznetsov/archive/2009/06/21/calculating-third-wednesday-of-the-month-with-inline-udfs.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I like Pieter Geerkens answer and I hope it has resolved your problem. The scalar function will return results for each of the matching rows wherever it is being used. So it is something similar to cursors. A table valued function will accept a set and return a set.

To verify the I\O changes between both processes, management studio might not help but on your own machine you can put a small trace to see what magnitude of performance you get.

Cheers!!